# How to get item's weight and row_weight on sales_quote_item_save_after

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, collection, addtocart, quoteitem

I would like to extract some information from a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` object while adding a product to the cart with the `sales_quote_item_save_after` event.

When I add a configurable product to the cart (e.g.: a white XL shirt), the event is triggered four times :

1. On `Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()` : it contains a `Quote Item` of the configurable product (e.g.: shirt) with prices and others data. It also contains the `Quote Item` associated to the simple product (white XL shirt) in a `_children` property
2. On `Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()` : it contains the `Quote Item` of the simple product that was in the `_children` property above. This one doesn't contain prices information as these are only on `configurable products`
3. On `Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()` : it contains the `Quote Item` of the 1st step, with more information, like the `weight` and the `row_weight`
4. On `Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()` : it contains the `Quote Item` of the 2nd step, also with more information

So, my issue is that i would like to work only on the 1st or the 2nd step (as the indexAction should not be affected by the module i'm working on), but on these 2 steps, i can't get the `weight` and the `row_weight` data.

So i've reviewed the Magento Core to get how these information are loaded on the `indexAction()` and it appears that when the `Mages_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection` is loaded, the `_afterLoad()` method executes `_assignProducts()` that load the weights and forwards them by a `setProduct()` method from the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` class.

Then, i tried to do this on my observer :

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
$item->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()->clear()->load()
```

After that, it appears that i can get the `weight` inside the :

```
`$item->getQuote()->getItemsCollection()->getFirstItem()`
```

Does anyone have a better solution or idea ? Because i'm not really satisfied with that one.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is, that the informations you want only are part of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` after `\Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals` is called.

This happens on the cart page and on every checkout step.

Threfore what you want to do (not hook on the `index` action) is not possible.

Just hook into the after_save event, make sure to track what you have already processed and do your thing.

Comment: How can i find customer add-to-cart overall weight @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221525/57334

Comment: I don't get the question. And I think you should open a new question and link this one.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221525/57334