# How to find Customer cart overall weight?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart, shopping-cart

How can I find customer cart overall weight?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
$cart_weight =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
    ->getQuote()
    ->getShippingAddress()
    ->getWeight();
```

Comment: Its working good, how can i display this option for only selected customer like using customer id.

Comment: This code should get the quote from the checkout session, So this will always display current customer cart weight

Comment: Okay, is any possible to show this option only for selected IP Address customer only. We don't need to display for all customer.

Comment: Yes of course, you can but you need to use pure PHP code ,  <?php if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"] == "{ip}"):?>

<?php endif; ?>

OR


<?php if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "{ip}"):?>

<?php endif; ?>

Comment: Pls check my code right :: https://justpaste.it/1jk26