# How to find which query is taking more time to execute in Magento 1 & Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database

Does anyone have an answer for below question?

How to find which query is taking more time to execute in Magento 1 & Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable profiler for that. To know how to enable it please check this.

**For Magento 1**

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-enable-the-magento-profiler.html

**For Magento 2**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Is any resource for magento 1?

Comment: Yes, please check https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-enable-the-magento-profiler.html

Comment: okay. i have one more doubt, how can i find selected customer cart overall weight?

Comment: @zus, it's not related to this question. Please create another question for that.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221525/57334